# Understanding sigwait() and how it sets parameters

Tags: c++, c, linux, multiprocessing, signals

The man page for sigwait() is a big confusing to me. The signature for sigwait is

```
 int sigwait(const sigset_t *set, int *sig);
```

Say I have code similar to the following

```
 sigset_t wset;
 sigemptyset(&wset);
 sigaddset(&wset,SIGHUP);
 sigaddset(&wget,SIGINT);
 sigaddset(&wget,SIGTERM);
 int sig;
 sigwait(&wset,&sig);
```

If I understand correctly, this will wait on a signal to be sent. If the signal is found in the signal set (i.e. **sigset_t wset**), it will set the signal number (i.e. **int sig**), as found in the set (i.e. **SIGHUP, SIGINT, SIGTERM** in this example). Otherwise, it will set the signal number to 0. Is my understanding correct?

I would try this out, but I don't have access to a compiler at the moment.

edit: for further clarification

Ok so, I send one of the signals above:

```
 int res = sigwait(&wset,&sig);
 // res = 0, sig = SIGHUP, SIGINT, or SIGTERM
```

And I send a signal not included in the set:

```
int res = sigwait(&wset,&sig);
// res = EINVAL (i.e. non-zero) and don't worry about sig
```

Is this correct?

Comment: You can try some online compiler

Answer (score 1):

As you say, in your example `sigwait` will wait for one of SIGHUP, SIGINT, SIGTERM.

> Otherwise, it will set the signal number to 0.

There is no otherwise. The only defined error is

> EINVAL The set argument contains an invalid or unsupported signal number.

**Edit**
To state this explicitly, the only defined error for this function is an invalid input for the `set` argument. As the set you constructed in your example is not invalid, the function will not return an error, it will wait until one of the signals arrives.

Comment: so the value for sig will be one of those three, else EINVAL?

Comment: No, @basil.  On success, which is indicated to you by a *return value* of 0, the function will set the signal number to one of `SIGHUP`, `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM`.  On failure, it *returns* an error code, with `EINVAL` being the only one documented, but (probably) does not modify the signal number at all.  If this function fails, you should not rely on or make any assumption about the value recorded in the signal number variable.  Setting the value of the object pointed to by the second argument is an altogether different thing from returning a value.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I included an edit example, would my understanding there be correct?

Comment: I added to the answer. Regarding the examples you added, the first is correct, you send a signal from the set, the function returns. The second is not correct. You send a signal not from the set, the function will continue to wait.

Comment: @RalfFriedl one thing I am noticing, now that I am at a linux machine, if i send it any signal, the process won't catch it and will die. I am doing this through **kill**. Am I missing something?

Comment: @basil Yes, any signal not in the mask passed to `sigwait` will behave normally.  What did you want to happen instead?

Comment: @zwol the problem is that it is not handling the signals that have been passed either

Comment: @basil I don't understand what you mean by "handling".  Please be more specific.  _Exactly_ what does it do, and what did you want to happen instead?